# Information about file extensions

Tags: installation, 13.10, file-format

Which type of file extensions are used in Ubuntu ?

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time

Answer (score 1):

### File extensions and datatypes

The concept of [file extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_extensions) is mostly antiquated and kept consistent as a convenience to the user, while the dataformats beneath may change. A very good example are todays Windows `.exe`-files, which have only very little in common with the `.exe`-files that were common during the 90s.

File extensions are rather recommendations or naming conventions for certain datatypes (or [MIME types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME)), which are mostly application specific. That is how most modern operating systems like Linux and Windows handle datatypes: When applications are installed, they register datatypes that they can handle in the system. That way the user can focus more on productivity by working with or using applications.

### Installing software

Open source Linux software is initially published as source code, or rather archives there of. Popular extensions/formats are `.tar.gz`, `.tar.bz` or the newer `.tar.xz`.

Some companies also publish closed source Linux software as compiled binaries in an installer with a `.run` extension along with installation instructions. **If you have problems installing proprietary software consult the offical documentation or contact the companies customer support.**

Distributions like Ubuntu package and publish source code as well as binaries. For the binaries the Debian specific package format with the extension `.deb` is used. Other distributions like Fedora use other extensions/formats, like `.rpm`.